# Sap Hybris ant initialize error: Exception in thread "AfterSaveEventPublisher-master"

Tags: tomcat, ant, sap-commerce-cloud, java-11

I am getting error when I initialized SAP Commerce 20.05 version.

`ant clean all` => BUILD SUCCESSFULL but, 
when I try `ant initialize` or `ant initialize -DtenantID=master` 
I am getting error: Exception in thread "AfterSaveEventPublisher-master" "de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant$TenantNotYetStartedException": tenant <> not yet started - got no active datasource

I am using default HSQL db options.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this a fresh installation? If yes, did you try executing one of the recipes?

Comment: We upgrade version of our customer's hybris platform, from 5.2 to 20.05. So, it is a fresh installation. I applied all commands from documentation. I tried both ant initialize and ant initialize -DtenantID=master. But, it didn't work.